# Views autorefresh

Tags: views, nodes

I've setup views autorefresh which works fine. But one thing I would like to achieve is instead of automatically loading the new articles if it would just create a notification say there is "1 new post" or "5 new posts", then when you click it, it then loads in the new posts.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more). Can you use it and let me know whether it has worked for you or not?

Comment: Oh looks pretty cool, will be testing this out tonight. Will let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: HI @adamhuxtable. Did it work?

Comment: Unfortunately not this is more of a replacement for Infinite Scroll for Views.